# Prove the binomial sum $\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{2n}{k} = \frac{n4^n}2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Prove $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{2n}{k} = \frac{n4^n}2$.
This is from section 0.241 of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's table of integrals.

I have managed to find a proof for this using the identity $k\binom nk = n \binom{n-1}{k-1}$.
Hence \begin{align*}
& \binom{2n}1+2\binom{2n}2+3\binom{2n}3+\cdots + n\binom{2n}n\\
&= 2n\binom{2n-1}0 + 2n\binom{2n-1}1 + 2n\binom{2n-1}2 + \cdots + 2n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\\
&= 2n\bigg[\binom{2n-1}0 + \binom{2n-1}1 + \binom{2n-1}2 + \cdots + \binom{2n-1}{n-1}\bigg]\\
&= 2n\left(\frac{2^{2n-1}}2\right)\\
&= n \cdot 2^{2n-1}
\end{align*}

I was wondering if there was another method to do this (such as using calculus as the coefficients suggest this may work). I was unable to find a calculus solution as I don't think I can use symmetry to remove the second half of the terms.

Comment: You are missing a $k$ in the summand, which should read $$\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{2n}{k}.$$

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo. I've fixed it.

Comment: The title and question in description seems to be different

Comment: If you define $f(x):=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{n}x^k$ so the desired result is $f^\prime(1)$, there might be a calculus-based solution exploiting $f(x)+x^{2n}f(1/x)=(1+x)^{2n}+\binom{2n}{n}x^n$. But it's not trivial: $x\mapsto1/x$ doesn't give an independent equation, and differentiating twice and setting $x=1$ gives equations in which $f(1),\,f^{\prime\prime}(1)$ appear, but not $f^\prime(1)$. I suspect expanding $x=1+\epsilon$ results to low orders in $\epsilon$ can circumvent this.

Answer (score 2):

Combinatorial proof here: from $2n$ children we select some (not more than half shall be selected) to be choirs, in addition we select one child from the choirs to be the leader.

**Left Hand Side**

We select $k$ children where $k$ can be anywhere from $1$ to $n$. Then we select one leader from these $k$ children. The number of possibilities is given below:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{k}\cdot\binom{k}{1}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot\binom{2n}{k}\\
\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\cdot\binom{2n}{k}
\end{align}
$$

**Right Hand Side**

Choose the leader first then each of the remaining $2n-1$ children either join the choir or don’t join. The number of possibilities is given below:

$$
2n\cdot 2^{2n-1}
$$

In half of these possibilities there are less than or equal to $n$ children in the choir and in the other half there are more than $n$ children in the choir. Therefore the number of possibilities we want is given below:

$$
\frac{1}{2}\times 2n\cdot 2^{2n-1}=\frac{n\cdot4^{n}}{2}
$$

**Conclusion**

Since both left and right hand side counts the same objects they must be equal

**Edit**

In case the last paragraph for the Right Hand Side is not obvious:

$$
\begin{align}
2^{2n-1}&=\sum_{i=0}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1}{i}\\
\\
&=2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{i}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

*Too complex solution based on algebra.*

Consider
$$k  \binom{2 n}{k} x^{k-1}=\Bigg[ \binom{2 n}{k} x^k\Bigg]'$$
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2 n}{k} x^k=(x+1)^{2 n}-\binom{2 n}{n+1} x^{n+1} \, _2F_1(1,1-n;n+2;-x)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function.

Computing the derivative with respect to $x$, we have
$$S'_n=2 n (x+1)^{2 n-1}-\frac{(n-1) \binom{2 n}{n+1} x^{n+1} \, _2F_1(2,2-n;n+3;-x)}{n+2}-$$ $$(n+1) \binom{2
   n}{n+1} x^n \, _2F_1(1,1-n;n+2;-x)$$

Now, making $x=1$ and using the properties of the gaussian hypergeometric function

$$S'_n=\sum_{k=0}^n k  \binom{2 n}{k} =n\,4^n-n\,2^{2 n-1} =n\,2^{2 n-1} $$